# Value of x of which a slope is undefined for a parametric graph.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

For what values of $x$ is the slope undefined for the graph

$$x=8-t^3$$

$$y=t^2-6t$$

The slope should be undefined when $\frac {dx}{dt}=0$.

$$\frac {dx}{dt}=-3 t^2$$

$$-3t^2=0$$

$$t=0$$

When $t=0$, $x=8$ so the $x$ value should be $8$, but the question was marked incorrect. What is incorrect in this?

Comment: Slope is undefiend when $\frac{dy}{dx}=\infty$. Note:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\div\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Comment: Yes - you are right

Comment: Yes - assuming you have indeed stated the question correctly

Comment: Then I agree - they marked your answer wrong incorrectly.

Comment: @Mufasa, I disagree with your first comment. What if the slope is $-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ ? It should be $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=0$ for the slope to be undefined. This covers both the undefined slopes $\tan\left(\pm\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas - my mistake, I should have stated slope is undefined when:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\infty$$Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was x=8, question incorrectly marked.